# Toast notification in windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-8.1

i am facing a weird problem. I am using [Windows phone 8.1 silverlight](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-phone-get-started/) and [Windows universal](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/) link for toast notification. I am able to get the toast notification in Windows Phone app it is nearly same way in Windows 8.1 as mentioned in the link. But toasts are not comming in Windows 8.1 part.

**Steps** :-

1 -> I have enabled the Toast from `Package.appxmanifest` file.

2 -> Then i have added this code in App.Xaml.cs in on_launched event as   mentioned

**It is showing the registeration successful as mentioned in the link**

```
private async void InitNotificationsAsync()
{
      var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
      var hub = new NotificationHub("<hub name>", "<connection string with listen access>");
      var result = await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(channel.Uri);

                // Displays the registration ID so you know it was successful
      if (result.RegistrationId != null)
      {
           var dialog = new MessageDialog("Registration successful: " + result.RegistrationId);
           dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));
       await dialog.ShowAsync();
      }
}
```

3 -> Now i send the notification from back end(**Hub is working in case of phone mpns notification**).

```
public static async void SendNotificationAsync()
{
        NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("<connection string with full access>", "<hub name>");
        var toast = @"<toast><visual><binding template=""ToastText01""><text id=""1"">Hello from a .NET App!</text></binding></visual></toast>";
        await hub.SendWindowsNativeNotificationAsync(toast);
 }
```

**Question** : -
Do you guys have a clue why it is not working in Windows 8.1 or what i am missing. This is the simplest example i am going through. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit** :- This is something interesting.

When i tried to send the notification from azure portal. From `DEBUG` tab of `My-NotificationHub` and from here i choose WNS toast then it showing an error.

`Error` - `The token obtained from the token provider is wrong`

but when i tried to send `MPNS` notification then there is no error. as i already mentioned it is working for `WP 8.1 silverlight MPNS toast`.

`What could be the cause of this error ?`

Answer (score 5):

Toast will not work on simulator, as stated in the MSDN documentation:

> Note  When testing toast notification code functionality through
>   Microsoft Visual Studio, you must use either the Local Machine or
>   Remote Machine debug setting on a Windows x86, x64, or Windows Runtime
>   machine. You cannot use the Visual Studio Simulator debug function
>   option—your code will compile and run in the Simulator, but the toast
>   will not appear.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868254.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly on Windows 8 the toast notifications did not work when I was using the simulator.  I had to deploy my Windows 8 application on my computer and not the simulator for me to be able to see toast notifications.